# How could I install and run kafka as a separate docker image than Zookeeper

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Here is the current Dockerfile I am using to install zookeeper and then run it on a CentOS container:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y --quiet install wget && yum -y --quiet install java-11-openjdk && yum -y --quiet autoremove && yum clean all  && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

RUN wget -q http://apache.forsale.plus/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.14/zookeeper-3.4.14.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf zookeeper-3.4.14.tar.gz
RUN mv zookeeper-3.4.14 /opt/zookeeper
RUN cp /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo_sample.cfg /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg

EXPOSE 2181 2888 3888

WORKDIR /opt/zookeeper

VOLUME ["/opt/zookeeper/conf", "tmp/zookeeper"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh"]
CMD ["start-foreground"]
```

What I am mostly confused about is how I would get two services to run as separate images/containers and yet still interact with each other. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45111909/12585645

I am also confused about how I would set it up as a cluster.
I would prefer not having to use docker compose if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a [Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and use the DNS service names between the images.

> how I would set it up as a cluster

If you don't want to use Compose, then `docker run` still works. Or use Terraform or Kubernetes/OpenShift

---

FWIW, I suggest you use existing Zookeeper and Kafka images rather than roll your own

Comment: Okay, not a problem!